# What is the meaning of n/a in RFC 4627 (JSON mime type)?

Tags: json, rest

In [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) is a section about the MIME-Type of JSON-encoded data.

```
6. IANA Considerations

   The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.

   Type name: application

   Subtype name: json

   Required parameters: n/a

   Optional parameters: n/a
```

Since the required and optional parameters are marked n/a, is it save to append own parameters to that content type, like `Content-Type: application/json; version=1.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most RFC identifiers, it is advisable to prefix your custom identifiers with `x-`, to avoid conflict with any future versions of the relevant specifications. `application/json` might not have a `version` parameter at this moment, but a future RFC might define it and you'll find your application and all data generated by in conflict with the new RFC, so a `x-version` parameter would be a better approach. I could not find any requirement that custom content-type *parameters* should be prefixed with `x-`, or indeed any mention that custom parameters are even allowed per the RFC, but it is safe to assume that no future official parameters will use that prefix. Just keep your parameter name a valid syntactic `token` and your value a valid syntactic `value` (both rules defined within [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-31)).

Answer (score 0):

As http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a states:

> n/a or N/A is a common abbreviation in tables and lists for not applicable, not available or no answer